# Yii2: Controller action not receiving parameter from route

Tags: parameters, routes, yii2

I have a weird issue that I think is configuration related. I have pretty urls on, and I have a route defined as:

```
'/customers/update/<id:\d+>' => '/customers/default/update'
```

And for good measure my action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {}
```

My controller is part of a module and maps correctly but my action doesnt seem to be receiving the parameter. If i leave out the parameter in the route and the action, the action gets called correctly and if I give the parameter a default value everything works as intended. To summarise, I get an error saying parameter 1 is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us an example of tried url

Comment: Put yours route configuration on first in `urlManager`. Because, may be this route crosses another default route like that `<module>/<controller>/<action>`.

Comment: This is a URL I'm trying: /customers/update/2  and this is the error I'm getting: 'Missing argument 1 for app\modules\customers\controllers\DefaultController::actionUpdate()'

I've also tried putting the route at the very top of my rules array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ugh, solved it. I was extending the wrong controller class... I was using

```
yii/base/Controller
```

instead of

```
yii/web/Controller
```

Could have been looking for this for a while...

Comment: This solution helped me to figure out   the same issue with  console\Controller.